# react-draggable: allow text selection inside <Draggable/> component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draggable

I am writing a React app in which some text will be displayed inside a draggable container. When the user clicks inside the container, but outside of the text, I want them to be able to drag the element around. When they click on the text, I want them to be able to do text selection and manipulation.

Right now, I am using react-draggable with the `<Draggable />` component. Is there any way to make this work? If not, is there an easy solution involving another library?

Comment: Same issue. Have you been able to solve it? I found this https://github.com/react-grid-layout/react-draggable/issues/384 but it doesn't fix my issue.